# Cannot get new image size PHP

Tags: php, function

**I am trying to get filesize of images from a specific folder AFTER and BEFORE they are optimized.**

I get same size for `$imgsize` as well as `$newsize` even though the latter appears AFTER they images are optimized. What i actually want is that it gets me the NEW size, not the old!

`$array` has the list of URLs for images (absolute URLs, belongs to another server)

(also let me know, is this fine that i'm replacing the same image after optimizing size in this part `$optimized_image= compress_image($path, $path, 50);` ) ?

Here is my code:

```
$f_path='newfolder';
foreach ($array as $imglink)
        {           
            $image = file_get_contents($imglink);
            $path= $f_path . "/" . basename($imglink);
            $new_image=file_put_contents($path , $image);
            $imgsize = filesize($path);
            $optimized_image= compress_image($path, $path, 50);
            $newsize = filesize($path);
            $percentage = ($imgsize / $newsize)*100;
            echo $imgsize . "<br/>"; //this size appears fine
            echo $newsize; //gives same size as above, no change!
        }
```

And here is the function i'm using for compressing image (which seem to work perfectly fine to me)

```
function compress_image($src, $dest , $quality) 
{
$info = getimagesize($src);

if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
{
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
}
elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
{
    $image = imagecreatefromgif($src);
}
elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
{
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($src);
}
else
{
    die('uknown format');
}

imagejpeg($image, $dest, $quality);
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use `clearstatcache`

Comment: Perfect! It worked. thanks! I'm going to check in detail how it affects the rest of the code, but for now, i've got my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @u_mulder for the answer. The `clearstatcache` worked perfectly and solved the problem! :) This is because it deletes the old variable data.